# Torch hdf5 data become zero when loading with h5py or matlab

Tags: python, machine-learning, hdf5, torch, h5py

I create a hdf5 file with torch hdf5, the meta data are torch.FloatTensor of size 14x14. When reading the result h5 file with torch hdf5, things seems right:

```
h5_path = opt.save_root..'attention_maps.h5'
myFile = hdf5.open(h5_path, 'r')
local data = myFile:read('/000182/20'):all()
print(data)
myFile:close()

Columns 1 to 10
-0.0040 -0.0015  0.0111  0.0289  0.0484  0.0660  0.0671  0.0435  0.0196  0.0040
-0.0006  0.0110  0.0344  0.0815  0.1434  0.2010  0.2137  0.1601  0.0730  0.0232
 0.0071  0.0239  0.0517  0.1165  0.2233  0.3453  0.3882  0.2917  0.1401  0.0467
 0.0104  0.0321  0.0647  0.1620  0.3068  0.4399  0.4460  0.3741  0.2036  0.0752
............. etc
[torch.FloatTensor of size 14x14]
```

But when loading with h5py or matlab, the data become all zeros:

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
         0.],
........................etc
dtype=float32
```

Is this something about datatype? Should I give the datatype when reading with python 
or matlab?

Comment: I regenerate the h5 file and things go right, maybe it was my mistake, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: for the record I just had this same issue occur, not with torch just a n HDF. I created a new HDF file from scratch and the issue went away, so this ended up being helpful. No idea what the issue is, since the HDF file appeared to be well formed.